# Not able to install New Relic’s Kubernetes integration (kubernetes-open-source-integration)

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, amazon-eks, newrelic

everyone
I am trying to get the New Relic Kubernetes integration installed in my Amazon EKS cluster. For that I am following the prompts displayed in the Kubernetes cluster Explorer: Auto-discovery section. At some point I get prompted to execute the following command :

```
curl -Ls https://download.newrelic.com/install/newrelic-cli/scripts/install.sh | bash && NR_CLI_CLUSTERNAME=<cluster-name> NR_CLI_NAMESPACE=newrelic NR_CLI_PRIVILEGED=true NR_CLI_LOW_DATA_MODE=true NR_CLI_KSM=true NR_CLI_KUBE_EVENTS=true NR_CLI_PROMETHEUS=true NR_CLI_LOGGING=true NEW_RELIC_API_KEY=<api-key-value> NEW_RELIC_ACCOUNT_ID=<account-id-value> /usr/local/bin/newrelic install -n kubernetes-open-source-integration
```

That being said I noticed that the *newrelic* cli gets installed but the terminal prompt just hangs there on the `newrelic install -n kubernetes-open-source-integration` part of the command and it never does anything it just hangs. When I am tired of waiting (after 30 minutes or so) I do a *ctrl+c* and I get the following message `^CFATAL could not fetch license key for account <account-id>: context canceled`

How can I get this **kubernetes-open-source-integration** properly installed in my Amazon EKS cluster ? What am I doing wrong ? Any help is welcomed.

Note: I have replaced the actual value of my cluster name, api key and account id in this issue description with respectively `<cluster-name>`, `<api-key-value>` and `<account-id-value>`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try with the user-api-key (NRAK-... format)?

Comment: Hi nabello, are you using [automated installer](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/kubernetes-pixie/kubernetes-integration/installation/kubernetes-integration-install-configure/#install-amazon-eks) to install it?

Comment: @FranxiHidro I tried using the User type (NRAK-... format) and the INGEST - LICENSE type. None of which worked and I got the same result.

Comment: @IvanM. Yes I am attempting to installed the *kubernetes-open-source-integration* via the automated installer.

Comment: Can you check the NRAK key and account id again on UI? Why you have to type the command **newrelic install** separately? You just need to run **curl -Ls** and It will use helm3 or kubectl to install the rest (maybe you should check kubectl version). Btw, you can open a ticket on newrelic one UI and they will support you.

Comment: @FranxiHidro I have checked those values a few times and re-ran the command provided a few times as well and same result. I am not running **newrelic install** separately I am explaining that the first part of the command provided installs the newrelic cli successfully and the second part never completes which is the **newrelic install** part. My *kubectl* and *helm* versions are up to date. I also opened a ticket on new relic which can be found [here](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/not-able-to-install-new-relics-kubernetes-integration-kubernetes-open-source-integration/177243/3).

Answer (score 1):

In the end I was not successful in getting the newrelic cli to install the *kubernetes-open-source-integration* but following [Install Kubernetes integration with Helm](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/kubernetes-pixie/kubernetes-integration/installation/install-kubernetes-integration-using-helm/#install-k8-helm) instructions I seem to have been able the install the Kubernetes New Relic integration using Helm on it’s own. Might help others in my situation regarding the newrelic cli malfunction.

Comment: Using helm or manifest is the simplest way, I have no idea why guided install cannot work.

Comment: I'm very happy to hear you found that page useful! ❤️